# Generating the convex hull of a subset of points while avoiding the other point containing in the generated convex hull

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, convex-hull

I have a set of 2-D points and I need to generate a convex hull such that the generated convex hull does not contain a certain subset of points in the original set. Actually, I am interested in generating the maximum-area convex hull which satisfies this requirement.

Is there any existing algorithm to achieve this? Is this problem NP-hard in nature?

Comment: There are plenty of convex hull algorithms. Can you add an example which shows the " does not contain a certain subset of points in the original set" restriction in action?

Comment: "in the original set" is superfluous.